# Notification not coming on lock screen

Tags: android

So I have a custom notification UI using remote views. I need to display the notification on Lock screen as well. I have added the PRIORITY_HIGH to the notification channel as well as the notification builder. Added VISIBILITY_PUBLIC as well. But I cant see the notification on Lock screen whereas the strange thing is that I can see the notification on my Pixel phone. I am using FCM for notification. Here is my code:

```
`val receiveCallIntent = Intent(this, VideoCallingActivity::class.java).apply {
                flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                RingtoneUtil.playRingtone()
            }

            val declineCallIntent =
                Intent(applicationContext, VideoCallNotificationReceiver::class.java).apply {
                    putExtra("CALL_RESPONSE_ACTION_KEY", "CANCEL_CALL_ACTION")
                    action = CANCEL_CALL_ACTION
                }

            val receiveCallPendingIntent = getPendingIntentForAcceptCall(receiveCallIntent)
            val cancelCallPendingIntent = getPendingIntentForDeclineCall(declineCallIntent)
            val remoteView = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.call_notification_layout)

            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView_caller_name, thingName)
           
            remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_accept, receiveCallPendingIntent)
            remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_reject, cancelCallPendingIntent)
            createVideoCallNotificationChannel()
            val notification = Builder(this, INCOMING_VIDEO_CALL_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_system_notification)
                .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                .setCustomContentView(remoteView)
                .setContentIntent(receiveCallPendingIntent)
                .setCustomHeadsUpContentView(remoteView)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + applicationContext.packageName + "/" + R.raw.video_call_ringtone), STREAM_VOICE_CALL)
                .setFullScreenIntent(receiveCallPendingIntent, true)
                .build()
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(INCOMING_VIDEO_CALL_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)`
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

I have added the PRIORITY_HIGH to the notification channel as well as the notification builder. Added VISIBILITY_PUBLIC as well

Comment: did you checked you enabled lock screen notifications in the app settings?
(found that it may be off by default)

Comment: @nope yes I checked that as well. its not happening only in the samsung device. Whereas in my pixel its working fine.